# SQL Server 2012 replication setup on routed network

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication

I'm trying to setup replication between two SQL Server 2012 instances.

I set up a publication successfully on `server1`, but then I had a problem when trying to access it from `server2`, because the only way I can reach `server1` is using a fully qualified domain name, e.g. `server1.mydomain.com`. The Netbios name `server1` on its own won't work because these two machines are not on the same subnet.

So I got an error saying I should connect to `server1`.

To try and get around it I renamed `server1` to `server1.mydomain.com`. But now I can't setup replication. I get the error:

> Could not connect to server 'server1' because distributor_admin is not defined as a remote login at the server.

Is there a way to get this working when the two nodes are on different subnets?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [distributor_admin is not defined as a remote login at the server.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/12/21/error-messages-and-the-solutions-related-to-distributor-admin-login.aspx) on blogs.msdn.com ?

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. The publisher and distributor are the same machine in my case.